# Trying to scrape a playoff bracket from wikipedia using beautiful soup. How do I identify the correct columns?

Tags: web-scraping, html-table, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to **scrape** the nhl playoff bracket from wikipedia, for the years 1988 on, using beautiful soup 4 in python. Inconsistent formatting (sometimes the there is more than one team on a row see: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2004_Stanley_Cup_playoffs) makes this hard.  I would like to identify the Team, Round, and Number of Games Won for every series in that year.

Initially, I converted the table to text and used regular expressions to identify the teams and the information, but the ordering shifts depending on whether the brackets allow more than one team per row or not.

Now I'm trying to work my way down the rows and count things like the number of cells/columns spans, but the results are inconsistent.  I'm missing how the 4th round teams are identified.

What I have so far is an attempt to count the number of cells before a cell with a team is reached...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
hockeyteams = ['Anaheim','Arizona','Atlanta','Boston','Buffalo','Calgary','Carolina','Chicago','Colorado','Columbus','Dallas','Detroit',
               'Edmonton','Florida','Hartford','Los Angeles','Minnesota','Montreal','Nashville','New Jersey',
               'Ottawa','Philadelphia','Pittsburgh','Quebec','San Jose','St. Louis','Tampa Bay','Toronto','Vancouver','Vegas','Washington',
               'Winnipeg','NY Rangers','NY Islanders']

#fetch the content from the url from the library
page_response = requests.get(full_link, timeout=5)
#use the html parser to parse the url
page_content = soup(page_response.content, "html.parser")

tables = page_content.find_all('table')
cnt = 0

#identify the appropriate table
for table in tables:
    if ('Semi' in table.text) & ('Stanley Cup Finals' in table.text):
        bracket = table
        break
row_num = 0        
for row in bracket.find_all('tr'):
    row_num += 1
    print(row_num,'#')
    colcnt = 0
    for col in row.find_all('td'):
        if "colspan" in col.attrs:
            colcnt += int(col.attrs['colspan'])
        else:
            colcnt += 1
        if (col.text.strip(' \n') in str(hockeyteams)):
            print(colcnt,col.text)
        
            
    print('col width:',colcnt)
```

Ultimately I'd like something like a dataframe that has:

Round Team A Team A Wins, Team B Team B Wins
1,   Tampa Bay, 4,   NY Islanders,   1 
2,   Tampa Bay, 4,   Montreal, 0

etc

Answer (score 0):

That table can be scraped with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
tables = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2004_Stanley_Cup_playoffs#Playoff_bracket')

bracket = tables[2].dropna(axis=1, how='all').dropna(axis=0, how='all')
print(bracket)
```

The output is full of `NaN`s, but it has what I think you're looking for and you can modify it using standard pandas methods.

Comment: Thanks, but I think the same problem occurs in that the column location extracted is not specific to the round.

Comment: I don't really understand. Can you post the table with the problem area and the way you expect it to be?

Comment: Running the code, the stanley cup final heading is in column 7, tampa bay is in column 4, and calgary is in column 3.    the second round series tampa/montreal appears in column 7.  I'm not sure what rules I could use that could accurately interpret this.